# scheduled service that starts a selenium test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, service, scheduled-tasks

I've been searching for a way to run my Selenium coded test as a service that runs every **x** minutes. I don't even know if it is possible to do so. I know how to create a service itself, but not how to execute the said test as a service.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a maven project containing selenium testcase, and then run than maven project as a service using available scheduler.

Comment: I appreciate the response! But i already found the solution, which was just use a create a Windows Service with Visual Studio, but also i checked Maven and it is another correct option. Thank you!